# MyGroups not implemented in Communicator.UIAutomation

Tags: silverlight, com, office-communicator

I'm working on a out of browser Silverlight app that provides some MS Office Communicator 2007 controls.  I'm using the [Automation SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=ED1CCE45-CC22-46E1-BD50-660FE6D2C98C&displaylang=en#RelatedDownloads).  The docs that were installed with the SDK state that there's a MyGroups property in the IMessenger2 interface, which will return the groups that a user has defined, but when I try to use it, I get a `NotImplementedException`.  Here's the code that I'm using:

```
dynamic communicator = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Communicator.UIAutomation");
communicator.AutoSignin();
foreach (dynamic g in communicator.MyGroups)
{
    //Do something with the group
}
```

If I replace MyGroups with MyContacts, I can get the contact list just fine.  Do I have to do something different to access properties in the IMessenger2 interface?  I've seen a few things on the web that say that MyGroups was deprecated for Windows Messenger, but from the docs, it seems like it should be available for MS Office Communicator.

If I can't use MyGroups, is there another way to get the groups that a user has created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the MyGroups property is marked as NotScriptable, meaning you can't call it in the way you are doing i.e. using the AutomationFactory. For security reasons, some properties and methods in the Automation API are not scriptable - this is to avoid malicious pages automating Communicator and carrying out certain tasks without you knowing.

It looks like the COM interop in Silverlight is treated in the same way as e.g. creating and calling the API from VBScript, so you won't be able to access any of the non-scriptable properties and methods. See the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758755%28office.12%29.aspx) for details of which properties and methods are not scriptable.

I'm guessing this is going to seriously hobble your app. I think what's hurting you is the decision to go with Silverlight OOB. Is there any way you could use WPF (or even winforms) rather than Silverlight? If you did this, you could reference the API directly, and have full access to all properties/methods.

Otherwise, I can't think of too many options. You can't trap the `OnContactAddedToGroup` event, as this is not scriptable.

It *might* be possible to wrap the API with a .NET assembly, and expose it via COM, then instantiate it in the same way - but the Not Scriptable might still be respected in that case, so it won't buy you anything. Hard to say without trying it, and still a fairly horrible solution.

**Edit**: I've just given the wrapper method a try (needed to do something similar as a proof of concept for a customer), and it seems to work. This is the way I did it:

Create a new .NET class library. Define a COM interface:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("8999F93E-52F6-4E29-BA64-0ADC22A1FB11")]
public interface IComm
{
    string GetMyGroups();
}
```

Define a class that implements that interface (you'll need to reference CommunicatorAPI.dll from the SDK):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[GuidAttribute("C5C5A1A8-9BFB-4CE5-B42C-4E6688F6840B")]
[ProgId("Test.Comm.1")]
public class Comm : IComm
{
    public string GetMyGroups()
    {
        var comm = new CommunicatorAPI.MessengerClass();

        var groups = comm.MyGroups as IMessengerGroups;
        return string.Join(", ", groups.OfType<IMessengerGroup>().Select(g => g.Name).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Build, and register using [RegAsm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28VS.71%29.aspx). Then call from the OOB silverlight app:

```
dynamic communicator = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Test.Comm.1");
MessageBox.Show(communicator.GetMyGroups());
```

Note, the same technique also works using the Lync API:

```
public string GetMyGroups()
{
    var comm = LyncClient.GetClient();
    return string.Join(", ", comm.ContactManager.Groups.Select(g => g.Name).ToArray());
}
```

Although this works, I can't really say whether it's a good practice, as it's working around a security restriction which was presumably there for a good reason. I guess the worst that could happen is that a malicious web page could potentially use the component, if it knew the ProgId of the control.

Edit: Also, using this method you'd need to be careful about memory leaks, e.g. make sure you're releasing COM objects when you're finished with them - easy enough to do, just needs a little discipline ;o)

Comment: Unfortunately, WPF isn't an option for us - that's a decision that was made way above my paygrade.  Looks like I get to present this to the higher ups and let them decide what to do.  Thanks!

Comment: I actually did the same test in between your edits , and came up with the same results :)  So at least there's a solution, even if it's not the greatest.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No worries. If this is getting raised upwards anyway, I'd seriously try and push for Lync and WPF - you could save yourself a whole lot of pain by using the in-built controls, and for any functionality not covered by the controls, you'd be working with a .NET API as opposed to a COM API. I've been working with the COM Automation API for a couple of years now, and trust me, it's no fun - it leads to a big dent in productivity, and opens up plenty of scope for hard-to-find errors. Whichever way you go, good luck!